# bootstrap изменил цвета элементов

Tags: bootstrap

Здравствуйте!
Поставил я значит такой bootstrap, и он поменял цвета текста на сайте, text-decoration: none; перестал работать вовсе.

С чем это может быть связанно и как пофиксить?

[image: Boostrap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно bootstrap подключен после вашего файла css, в результате переопределяет классы для элементов, стоит изменить порядок подключения, чтобы ваш файл подключался после bootstrap.

Можно добавить !important к некоторым свойствам селектора.

В целом, по такому описанию проблемы очень сложно сказать, что там происходит. Можно посмотреть стили в разделе Styles в devTools в Google Chrome, можно будет узнать у какого класса приоритет выше на определенном элементе.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь приоритеты классов , bootstrap перебивает стили  , как и его tetx-decoration , скорее всего bootstrap подключен после твоего файла стилей 
В среде разработчика легче всего искать проблему связанную с css